# Editing Multiple Rows by Their Order Index

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

**Q:** How would I go about using / applying the row number of each row in a query to a certain column in the entire query?

I've added a screenshot to try and make things more obvious:
[image]

[The picture is only a simple example]

I would like to be able to directly use the value of the row number in such a context.
(Iterate over the values, somehow?)

Thanks in advance.
(Sorry if the question is a bit vague)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this :

```
;WITH TEST AS 
( 
SELECT *,  
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS RowNo 
FROM [UserTable]
) 
UPDATE TEST  
SET  myindex = RowNo
```

Comment: EXCELLENT! That is exactly the tool I've been looking for. Thank you very much.