# Cursor not incrementing updating row with start value

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I'm very new to SQL Server. I'm using a cursor to populate a table with ids; I just discovered cursors today. The code is running but it is populating each row with the start value.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE  @Irow  int    
declare @cheese int;
set @cheese = (select (max(balanceid) + 1) from balancetbl)
DECLARE aurum CURSOR FOR
SELECT    @Irow
FROM      aurumaugupload
OPEN aurum
FETCH aurum INTO @Irow
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
update aurumaugupload set balanceid = @cheese
set @cheese = @cheese + 1;
FETCH aurum INTO @Irow             
END
CLOSE aurum
DEALLOCATE aurum
RETURN
```

I think it's a really basic error but I can't see it due to my inexperience.

UPDATE: thanks guys for your prompts answers. I got it working after nonnb's help. Here's the final code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE  @acc  int    
declare @start int;
set @start = (select (max(balanceid) + 1) from balancetbl)
DECLARE aurum CURSOR FOR
SELECT    accountid
FROM      aurumaugupload
OPEN aurum
FETCH aurum INTO @acc
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
update aurumaugupload set balanceid = @start where accountid = @acc
set @start = @start + 1;
FETCH aurum INTO @acc          
END
CLOSE aurum
DEALLOCATE aurum
RETURN
```

Comment: Cursors are very inefficient and should only be used in a very small number of cases. This doesn't look to be one of them. Perhaps explain what the intention of the query is.

Comment: hey martin. i understand. im updating a table with id's generated from the max value from another table. like i said, im very new to sql server and im trying to avoid doing it manually in Excel.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean it doesn't matter..

Comment: If the sorting order doesn't matter then you should try my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 bugs here:

Bug 1

```
DECLARE aurum CURSOR FOR
SELECT    @Irow
FROM      aurumaugupload
```

will select the same (unitialised)  constant for every row of aurumaugupload
You need something like

```
SELECT    Irow
FROM      aurumaugupload
```

Bug 2 - You are updating all rows within the cursor. You need a where

```
update aurumaugupload set balanceid = @cheese
where IRow = @IRow;

set @cheese = @cheese + 1
```

Comment: what would be the better solution?

Comment: @Midiane - Regarding a better solution see [this recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608837/editing-multiple-rows-by-their-order-index/7608946#7608946) for something similar to what I think you are doing.

Comment: @MartinSmith damn. That's MUCH easier. Appreciate the headsup :)

Answer (score 1):

Your update statement doesn't have a where clause, so you are updating every row each time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution (if the sorting/update order doesn't matter):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE  @Irow  int    
DECLARE @cheese int;
SET @cheese = (SELECT (MAX(balanceid) ) FROM balancetbl)

UPDATE aurumaugupload 
set    @cheese = balanceid = @cheese+1;
```